# JSON dump: TypeError: Object of type int64 is not JSON serializable

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary, topic-modeling

I have the following class to train topic models:

```
class LDA_Model:
    def __init__(self, data_words_model):
        self.data_words = data_words_model
        self.id2word = corpora.Dictionary(self.data_words)
        self.corpus = [self.id2word.doc2bow(text) for text in self.data_words]
    
    def get_coherence(self, model, coherence):
        coh_model = CoherenceModel(model=model, texts= self.data_words, dictionary=self.id2word, coherence=coherence)
        return coh_model.get_coherence()
        
    def build_models(self, start, limit, step, runs):           
        crossval_dict = dict()
        for run in range(runs):
            coherence_dict = dict()
            topic_dict = dict()
        
            for num_topics in range(start, limit, step):
                start = time.time()

                model = LdaModel(corpus=self.corpus,
                                 id2word=self.id2word,
                                 num_topics=num_topics, 
                                 random_state=100,
                                 update_every=1,
                                 chunksize=100,
                                 passes=50,
                                 alpha='auto',
                                 per_word_topics=True)

                coherence_dict[num_topics] = {'c_v':self.get_coherence(model, 'c_v'), 
                                              'u_mass':self.get_coherence(model, 'u_mass'), 
                                              'c_uci':self.get_coherence(model, 'c_uci'), 
                                              'c_npmi':self.get_coherence(model, 'c_npmi')}

                topic_dict[num_topics] = model.show_topics()

                dump = open(PATH+"LDA_coherences.json", "w")
                json.dump(coherence_dict, dump)
                dump.close()

                dump = open(PATH+"LDA_topics.json", "w")
                json.dump(topic_dict, dump)
                dump.close()
                end = time.time()
            
                print('Calculating topics for ', str(num_topics), 'number of topics, took: ', str(int(end-start)), ' seconds.')
    
            crossval_dict[run] = {'coherence_dict': coherence_dict,
                              'topic_dict':topic_dict}
            dump = open(PATH+"10runs_LDA.json", "w")
            json.dump(crossval_dict, dump)
            dump.close()
        return coherence_dict
```

After I run:

```
ldamodel = LDA_Model(data_words)
coherence = ldamodel.build_models(start = 5, limit= 71, step= 5, runs=10)
```

The model runs fine for the first two `num_topcis` (5 and 10). Output so far:

```
>>> Calculating topics for  5 number of topics, took:  1109  seconds.
>>> Calculating topics for  10 number of topics, took:  1485  seconds.
```

However, with 15 topics it terminates and throws the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-eb870528e17d> in <module>
----> 1 coherence = ldamodel.build_models(start = 5, limit= 71, step= 5, runs=10)

<ipython-input-30-09de1b2cf22a> in build_models(self, start, limit, step, runs)
     55 
     56                 dump = open(PATH+"LDA_topics.json", "w")
---> 57                 json.dump(topic_dict, dump)
     58                 dump.close()
     59                 end = time.time()

~\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py in dump(obj, fp, skipkeys, ensure_ascii, check_circular, allow_nan, cls, indent, separators, default, sort_keys, **kw)
    177     # could accelerate with writelines in some versions of Python, at
    178     # a debuggability cost
--> 179     for chunk in iterable:
    180         fp.write(chunk)
    181 

~\Anaconda3\lib\json\encoder.py in _iterencode(o, _current_indent_level)
    429             yield from _iterencode_list(o, _current_indent_level)
    430         elif isinstance(o, dict):
--> 431             yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)
    432         else:
    433             if markers is not None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\json\encoder.py in _iterencode_dict(dct, _current_indent_level)
    403                 else:
    404                     chunks = _iterencode(value, _current_indent_level)
--> 405                 yield from chunks
    406         if newline_indent is not None:
    407             _current_indent_level -= 1

~\Anaconda3\lib\json\encoder.py in _iterencode_list(lst, _current_indent_level)
    323                 else:
    324                     chunks = _iterencode(value, _current_indent_level)
--> 325                 yield from chunks
    326         if newline_indent is not None:
    327             _current_indent_level -= 1

~\Anaconda3\lib\json\encoder.py in _iterencode_list(lst, _current_indent_level)
    323                 else:
    324                     chunks = _iterencode(value, _current_indent_level)
--> 325                 yield from chunks
    326         if newline_indent is not None:
    327             _current_indent_level -= 1

~\Anaconda3\lib\json\encoder.py in _iterencode(o, _current_indent_level)
    436                     raise ValueError("Circular reference detected")
    437                 markers[markerid] = o
--> 438             o = _default(o)
    439             yield from _iterencode(o, _current_indent_level)
    440             if markers is not None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\json\encoder.py in default(self, o)
    177 
    178         """
--> 179         raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
    180                         f'is not JSON serializable')
    181 

TypeError: Object of type int64 is not JSON serializable
```

So, it seems like I cannot serialize the `topic_dict`as it contains an object of type 'int64'. However, this surprises me as it did work in the first two runs.

What causes the error? And what can I do to overcome this error?

Answer (score 0):

Gensim's `show_topics` method returns maximum 10 topics on default. However, when more topics are produced, it selects 10 topics only. I have not checked the source code, but expect that since this selection is a Numpy operation, the type of each index changes as well:

```
for top in ldamodel.topic_dict[5]:
    print(type(top[0]),type(top[1]))
<class 'int'> <class 'str'>
<class 'int'> <class 'str'>
<class 'int'> <class 'str'>
<class 'int'> <class 'str'>
<class 'int'> <class 'str'>


for top in ldamodel.topic_dict[10]:
    print(type(top[0]),type(top[1]))
<class 'int'> <class 'str'>
<class 'int'> <class 'str'>
<class 'int'> <class 'str'>
<class 'int'> <class 'str'>
<class 'int'> <class 'str'>
<class 'int'> <class 'str'>
<class 'int'> <class 'str'>
<class 'int'> <class 'str'>
<class 'int'> <class 'str'>
<class 'int'> <class 'str'>

for top in ldamodel.topic_dict[15]:
    print(type(top[0]),type(top[1]))
<class 'numpy.int64'> <class 'str'>
<class 'numpy.int64'> <class 'str'>
<class 'numpy.int64'> <class 'str'>
<class 'numpy.int64'> <class 'str'>
<class 'numpy.int64'> <class 'str'>
<class 'numpy.int64'> <class 'str'>
<class 'numpy.int64'> <class 'str'>
<class 'numpy.int64'> <class 'str'>
<class 'numpy.int64'> <class 'str'>
<class 'numpy.int64'> <class 'str'>
```

To overcome this problem, I used the following line in my class:

`topic_dict[num_topics] = model.show_topics(num_topics = num_topics)`